# Regex: trying to match two strings *without* a certain char in between

Tags: regex, grep, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match a line w/"function" followed by "insert" as a whole word, that *doesn't* have "$" in between. That means it should match

```
function static insert()
```

but not

```
function insertRecord($insert)
```

I've tried negative lookahead/behind such as:

```
function.*(?!\$).*\binsert\b
```

but nothing.

I've been trying this on grep 2.6.3 on Ubuntu 15.10 and PhpStorm (the latter in which I put less stock). And yes, I have been putting my regexes in single quotes for grep. I've also tried https://www.regex101.com, which seems to agree, that I'm using this wrong. I've even tried abbreviated versions on the tester site, but I don't know what part of

```
function.*(?!\$)
```

it doesn't understand.

A consistent problem in all my experiments is that it keeps hitting on lines where a "$" precedes the "insert".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function[^$]*\binsert\b
```

This just uses a negated character class `[^$]` to restrict the chars between to disallow any dollar signs.

You already figured out that you need word boundaries `\b` around "insert".